# How to lookup a variable and use the outcome to match in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
$installLocation = "C:\hello\world"
$packageName = "hello"

Write-Host "if ("$installLocation" -match '${packageName}|bla') {"

if ("$installLocation" -match '${packageName}|bla') {
    Write-Host "hello";
}

if ("$installLocation" -match 'hello|bla') {
    Write-Host "world";
}
```

**Current outcome**

```
if ( C:\hello\world -match 'hello|bla') {
world
```

**Expected outcome**

```
if ( C:\hello\world -match 'hello|bla') {
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes around variables.

Try this:

```
$packageName = "hello"
echo '${packageName}|bla'
echo "${packageName}|bla"
```

Result is:

```
${packageName}|bla
hello|bla
```

So to fix the script, use:

```
if ("$installLocation" -match "${packageName}|bla") {
    Write-Host "hello";
}
```

which gives the result:

```
hello
world
```